# Test Average and Grade with two additional functions

Tags: python, function, average

I have been at this for a while, and I am stuck. I have to write a program that asks the user for each score and the average test score. I need the functions calcAverage which accepts five test scores and returns the average of the scores. determineGrade which accepts a score and returns the grade as a string based off the standard grading scale (90-100 is an A, 80-89 is a B, 70-79 is a C, etc). But I also need a function for getValidScore which prompts and reads a single valid test score and once the score is has been input it returns to the calling module. And finally isInValidScore is a function that checks whether a passed test score is in range from 0-100 and returns a Boolean letting me know if it's valid.
Here's what I have:

```
def main():

   test1 = int(input('Enter test grade 1: '))
   test2 = int(input('Enter test grade 2: '))
   test3 = int(input('Enter test grade 3: '))
   test4 = int(input('Enter test grade 4: '))
   test5 = int(input('Enter test grade 5: '))

   grade = (test1 + test2 + test3 + test4 + test5)

   input('press enter to continue')
   print(calc_average)
   print(determine_grade)
   print(getValidScore)
   print(isInvalidScore)
   return;

def calcAverage():

   grade / 5
   return averageScore

def determinGrade(score):
   if grade >= 90 and grade <= 100:
       return 'A'
   elif grade >= 80 and grade <= 89:
       return 'B'
   elif grade >= 70 and grade <= 79:
       return 'C'
   elif grade >= 60 and grade <= 69:
       return 'D'
   else:
       return 'F'

def getValidScore():
   grade = int(input('input score'))isInvalidScore(score)
   while isInvalidScore == false:
       print('ERROR')
   grade = int(input('input correct score'))
   return score

def isInvalidScore(score):
   status = True
   if score < 0 or score > 100:
      status = True
   else: status = False
   return status

main()
```

So I added returns and when I run the program, I get this:

Enter test grade 1: 99

Enter test grade 2: 88

Enter test grade 3: 77

Enter test grade 4: 66

Enter test grade 5: 55

press enter to continue

function calc_average at 0x02BAD228>

function determine_grade at 0x02BAD270>

function getValidScore at 0x02BAD2B8>

function isInvalidScore at 0x02BAD300>

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong here:

1. You're printing out the function itself which is represented by the location in memory, not the result of execution. Add parentheses to the ends of your calls to print out the result.
2. You should be calling `getValidScore` and return an integer result instead of reading in input without validation (see `main`).
3. Some of your functions take parameters, but you aren't passing any (hint: `determinGrade`, `isInvalidScore`).
4. Some of your functions *should* take parameters (hint: `calcAverage`).
5. calcAverage should return a real number with the actual average. (hint: `return grade/5`)
6. Your `while` loop should start with `while isInvalidScore(grade)`, making the call on the previous line unnecessary.
7. In `main`, you're calling an undefined function (`determine_grade`, is it a typo?)

That's all I can see on a quick look of it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @tdlive aw'sum is actualy really good (I just upvoted it). Read his comments and work with the stuff. I will supply you with a correction implementation.. I hope you study the aspects you dont understand but take away some good parts from it. Best of luck.

```
isValidScore = lambda n: 0 <= n <= 100

calcAverage = lambda *args: sum(args)/len(args)

determinGrade = lambda s: ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'][max(0, (min(60, 99)/10)-5)]

def getValidScore():
   while True:
        try:
            if isValidScore(int(raw_input('Input score: '))):
                return score              
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print('Score has to be an integer in the range 0 to 100')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scores = []
    for _ in range(5):
        scores.append(getValidScore())
    print('\nThe scores are: ' + str(scores))
    print('The average is: ' + str(calcAverage(*scores)))
    print('The grade is: ' + determinGrade(calcAverage(*scores)))
```

Comment: @Andy, do you think I need to explain the code step by step or is this sufficient?